# How to put \vspace above the title? Or some way to make the first page having different top margin?

Tags: spacing, margins

The conference needs a paper's first page margin to be `{top=72pt, bottom=54pt, left=54pt, right=54pt}` and the rest to be `{top=54pt, bottom=54pt, left=54pt, right=54pt}`.

I tried package `\newgeometry` at exactly where page 1 ends, but it causes one of my cross-column figure (which is supposed to show at the top of page 2) to show at the top of page 3. The figure stubbornly shows at page 3 even if I define it right after `\newgeometry` (or `\newgeometry \clearpage`, which has no different effect).

After many tries failed, I gave up in using `\newgeometry`. I turned to try `\vspace`, inserting `\vspace{18pt}` above `\title{...}`. Unfortunately it seems not working at this position.

Comment: What if you put `figure*` environment *before* `\newgeometry`. Don't forget it systematically goes at the top of the next page. Other possibility: loading the `stfloats` package.

Comment: @Bernard If ```figure*``` is put before ```\newgeometry```, the figure will show on a new page, which contains only the figure, after page 1. And I tried ```{figure*}[H}``` from ```stfloats``` package, resulting the figure... just disappeared?

Comment: To modify the layout of the  title, you have the `titling` package, which defines a `\droptitle` length, to change the vertical position of the title. Other than this, you should post a minimal compilable code illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `\vspace` is that spacing is discarded at the top of the page. Instead use `\vspace*` to provide extra white space at the start of the article. I would not go through the trouble of fiddling with changing geometry or inserting empty figures.

Also, the `\title` command is a declaration that does not typeset anything directly.  It is `\maketitle` that formats everything, so make sure the `\vspace*` goes above that. Better yet, `\maketitle` should include all the necessary spacing, and, ideally, your conference (and journal) would have a document class that had all the right margins, spacing, and layout defined.